# How to throw error after subscription timeout?

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I'm simply trying to display in the view ( when for example user's connection is too slow and results won't come from subscription) after 30 seconds.
I'm surely missing something because even when results all arrive, the console timeout error message is still appearing.
This is what I tried:

```
searchInfo() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.info= [];
    const source = this.infoService.searchInfo('help');
    source.pipe(
        timeout(30000),
        takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
    ).subscribe((infoTable: infoTableContent) => {
        this.info.push(infoTable);
        this.isLoading = false;
    }),
        (err) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            console.log(err, 'Sorry, ...')  //not working
        }
```

I want to be able to display a message like "Sorry, took too long to retrieve data" after 30 seconds of trying to subscribe.
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

When I run this with Mocked Services it runs just fine for me:

```js
const mockService = {
  searchInfo: msg => NEVER.pipe(startWith({key: msg}))
};
const onDestroy$ = timer(5000);
let isLoading = true;
const info = [];
mockService.searchInfo('help').pipe(
  timeout(1000),
  takeUntil(onDestroy$)
).subscribe({
  next: (mockTable: any) => {
    info.push(mockTable);
    isLoading = false;
  },
  error: err => {
    isLoading = false;
    console.log('Sorry, ...', err);
  }
});
```

I suspect your bug might be due to miss-formatting (brackets in the wrong place etc)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `)` right after your `next` callback in the `subscribe`.
Therefore, your `error` callback is ignored.

```ts
.subscribe((infoTable: infoTableContent) => {
  this.info.push(infoTable);
  this.isLoading = false;
}), // <-- This paranthesis closes the subscribe method
```

The following works as expected

```ts
.subscribe(
  (infoTable: infoTableContent) => {
    this.info.push(infoTable);
    this.isLoading = false;
  },
  (err) => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    console.log(err, 'Sorry, ...');
  }
);
```